# Should I buy a really old domain for the purpose of ranking higher in Google?

Tags: domains, google-ranking

Will a domain that is fifteen years old with no backlinks rank higher in Google than a 6 month old domain name with no backlinks?

Let's take keywords in domain out of the equation and they would both be the same extension.

Comment: No, that is about domain registration length. This is about purchasing a domain that has age based on who.is data.

Comment: You'd have to buy one that is not expired. Since whois data resets when it expires. Also, you would need to make sure the domain is relevant to the content your going to serve, otherwise it'll pass irrelevance which is not something you want. Assuming that its relevant, purchased before expiring then yes it would be beneficial and is very common.

Answer (score 3):

Age of domain is a **huge** trust factor for a domain. It is important.

However, as Simon Hayter alludes to, there is more complication to this than just the domain age. For example, when the domain is transferred and the registration information changes, the domain age no longer matters. The domain age, in effect, actually resets within Google.

Why?

Simple answer.

The trust was earned by the previous owner and not by the new owner. It is not uncommon for a domain name to be snatched-up by a monetizer that then flogs the boggie-snots out of any value the domain has until it is completely leached into the soil then sells the domain name to some poor schlub that pay thousands of dollars for the privilege of buying excrement.

Okay. That was a bit colorful. Hopefully humorous too. However, I think I made my point. Right??

Comment: I don't agree with Google automatically reset trust factor when who is data changed. Yes that may be reset, but only when domain is expired too long ago, and return same default page from domain company. But If Domain is recently dropped and someone buy that within few weeks, then it will not going to reset. It is common, when company with two founders transfer ownership to other founder. I am saying this because I have seen people still building PBN sites with expired domain, and ranks very high in serp within short time, so if Google reset like this, then it does not happen with them :)

Comment: @Goyllo Anytime a domain name is transferred the Whois data has changed. Google does asses the change for some level of continuity and whether the domain can be trusted. If for example, it appears that the transfer is within a company, then that would be okay. You are 100% right about that! However, if there is not relationship that can be found, then the trust metrics for the domain are reset. Sorta. If a domain continues in a trustworthy way, then I believe that trust is regained fairly quickly. Google does consider a domain transfer a reset, however. They have to.

Comment: Closetnoc@OK, so, how google can see this domain is transfer to relative? By checking webmaster history from search console, or analytic? What if webmaster don't use anything from Google? As per my assumption it only reset when dropped domain does not sell within few weeks. For example, if Google crawl that domain and see the default domain page for a long time then they will reset it, because the original webmaster finally shutdown their business. It does not reset if Who is info is changed, as far as I know. Cheers !

Comment: @Goyllo I know that if registration information changes where it is clear that the domain has transferred to another party, Google does reset some metrics, however, these metrics are not forgotten. I know this from internal schema and business logic documentation I got directly from G a few years ago as part of the research on network trust systems and methods we were developing. We were sharing information back and forth on the topic. G was very interested in what we were doing and how it could be applied. Registration change can and will effect domain trust. It is common sense at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The length of time a domain has been registered, and up and running, does help with SEO but, as the saying goes, content is king and it is your content that will determine your rank going forward. Length of time of the domain name is only a brownie point.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly my notion on the subject, if you put a garbage site up on a aged domain it means nothing. For me the critical point is within the first couple of months of a domain being registered; Matt Cutts said that domain age beyond the six month period is an extremely low signal, almost zero.